# Nodemailer sending mail slowly

Tags: node.js, send, nodemailer

I have a problem when using nodemailer-pool to send my email.

I create some pool for every sender email, and then start my program to send email while it get info from rabbit mq.

At first, it worked well, but after some days (maybe 3 days), it became very very slow to send mail, should I do something to fix such issue?

My code is below.

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var smtpPool = require('nodemailer-smtp-pool');
var senderConfig = require('../../utils/senderConfig');
```

Utils:

```
var sender1 = senderConfig.smtp_server_list["sender1"];
var sender1Tp = createTransporter(sender1);

var sender2 = senderConfig.smtp_server_list["sender2"];
var sender2Tp = createTransporter(sender2);

var sender3 = senderConfig.smtp_server_list["sender3"];
var sender3Tp = createTransporter(sender3);

var sender4 = senderConfig.smtp_server_list["sender4"];
var sender4Tp = createTransporter(sender4);

var sender5 = senderConfig.smtp_server_list["sender5"];
var sender5Tp = createTransporter(sender5);


function generateBounceAddress(recipient, sender, len) {
    var baseStr = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var bsaeStrLen = baseStr.length;
    var bounceAddress = "bounce+";
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++) bounceAddress += baseStr.charAt(Math.random() * bsaeStrLen);

    bounceAddress += "-" + recipient.replace("@","=") + "@" + sender.slice(sender.indexOf("@")+1);

    return bounceAddress;
}


function createTransporter(sender) {
    console.log("createTransporter: ", sender.host);

    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpPool({
        host: sender.host,
        port: sender.port,
        authMethod: sender.authMethod,
        auth: {
            user: sender.user,
            pass: sender.pass
        },
        maxConnections: 3,
        maxMessages: 500
    }));

    return transporter;
}
```

---

```
module.exports = {
    sendOneMail : function(email, callback) {
        var sender = senderConfig.smtp_server_list[email.sender];
        // if (!transporterPool[sender.user]) transporter = createTransporterPool(sender);
        // else transporter = transporterPool[sender.user];
        // messagePool[sender.user]--;

        var bounceAddress;
        var mailOptions = {};
        var senderUser = (sender.name) ? sender.name+" <"+sender.user+">" : sender.user;
        if (email.senderName) senderUser = email.senderName+" <"+sender.user+">";

        if (email.recipient.indexOf(",") >= 0) {
            mailOptions = {
                from: senderUser,
                to: email.recipient,
                subject: email.subject,
                html: email.content
            };
        }
        else {
            bounceAddress = generateBounceAddress(email.recipient, sender.user, 5);

            mailOptions = {
                from: senderUser,
                to: email.recipient,
                envelope: {
                    from: bounceAddress,
                    to: email.recipient
                },
                headers: {
                    'X-RETURN-PATH': bounceAddress
                },
                subject: email.subject,
                html: email.content
            };
        }

    // 美国
        if (email.sender === "sender1") sender1Tp.sendMail(mailOptions, callback);
        if (email.sender === "sender2") sender2Tp.sendMail(mailOptions, callback);
        if (email.sender === "sender3") sender3Tp.sendMail(mailOptions, callback);
        if (email.sender === "sender4") sender4Tp.sendMail(mailOptions, callback);
        if (email.sender === "sender5") sender5Tp.sendMail(mailOptions, callback);

    }
}
```